# Undertow handlers make all stack Non-Blocking

Tags: java, wildfly, reactive-programming, nonblocking, undertow

I'm studying undertow because I've seen is a good choice if you want to implement Non-Blocking IO and you want to have a reactive http listener.

Undertow uses handlers to handle http requests in a Non-Blocking way.

If I have some logic to be implemented between request and response, how to make this logic to be Non-Blocking too, inside of an undertow handler?

I mean, if it's inserted (or called) within the ***handleRequest()*** method is already dispatched to a working thread and *then already Non-Blocking* or do you need to use **CompletableFuture, or Rx Observable** or any other reactive library, in order to guarantee that all the stack is reactive?

This is my Handler class as a title of example, I simulate to read a Json which will be parsed into a Person.class object and the transformed (business logic) and then returned back as a Json response.

I've written the two alternatives, in order to understand better how to make the whole stack reactive and Non-Blocking.
Which one do I have to use?

```
public class DoBusinessLogicHandler  implements HttpHandler {

  JsonConverter json = JsonConverter.getInstance();

  @Override
  public void handleRequest(HttpServerExchange exchange) throws Exception {
    if (exchange.isInIoThread()) {
        exchange.dispatch(this);
        return;
    }

    Pooled<ByteBuffer> pooledByteBuffer = exchange.getConnection().getBufferPool().allocate();
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = pooledByteBuffer.getResource();
    byteBuffer.clear();
    exchange.getRequestChannel().read(byteBuffer);
    int pos = byteBuffer.position();
    byteBuffer.rewind();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[pos];
    byteBuffer.get(bytes);
    byteBuffer.clear();
    pooledByteBuffer.free();

    String requestBody = new String(bytes, Charset.forName("UTF-8") );

    /* FIRST ALTERNATIVE:
    you can call the business logic directly because the whole body of handleRequest() is managed reactively
     */
    Person person = (Person) json.getObjectFromJson(requestBody, Person.class);
    Person p = transform(person);
    sendResponse(exchange, json.getJsonOf(p));


    /* SECOND ALTERNATIVE
    you must wrap business logic within a reactive construction (RxJava, CompletableFuture, ecc.) in order to
    have all the stack reactive
     */
    CompletableFuture
            .supplyAsync(()-> (Person) json.getObjectFromJson(requestBody, Person.class))
            .thenApply(p -> transform(p))
            .thenAccept(p -> sendResponse(exchange, json.getJsonOf(p)));

  }

  /* it could be also a database fetch or whatever */
  private Person transform(Person p){
    if(p!=null){
        p.setTitle(p.getTitle().toUpperCase());
        p.setName(p.getName().toUpperCase());
        p.setSurname(p.getSurname().toUpperCase());
    }
    return p;
  }

  private void sendResponse(HttpServerExchange exchange, String response){
    exchange.getResponseHeaders()
            .put(Headers.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
    exchange.getResponseSender()
            .send(response);
  }


}
```